# how to strike out text when a user hovers over it

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a user hovers over a button I want to strike out the text.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
button{  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline:none;
  color: white;
}

body{
background-color: black
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Any suggestion please

Comment: a black line stroke and in the middle of the text if the height is 10 px then the stroke should be at 5px

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `:hover` selector then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the **[`:hover` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover)** and the **[`text-decoration` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)**.

And, really, if you just want text and aren't really making a clickable `button`, you can use just about any element, but a `div` allows you to remove all the styling you had to make the button not look like a button.

```css
body { background-color: black }
div { color: white; cursor:pointer; }
div:hover { text-decoration:line-through; }
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```css
.btn-stroke{ 
      background-color: Transparent;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      border: none;
      cursor:pointer;
      overflow: hidden;
      outline:none;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    /* Create a stroke with 0% of width */
    .btn-stroke:after{
      display: block;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: 0%;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #000;
      transition: width 0.5s;
    }
    /* Using hover :pseudo-class increase width  */
    .btn-stroke:hover:after {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    body{
       background-color: black
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn-stroke">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Please don't post your solution to 3rd party links as those links can die over time. Just include your code in a "code snippet", right here in your answer. Also, please include explanations in your answer so that it can be understood by the readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you code updated.

```
<button>Hello</button>




button {
      background-color: Transparent;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow: hidden;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
    }

    body {
      background-color: black
    }

    button:hover {
      text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

You have to add only hover on your button, and text-decoration: line-through;